# Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup No Match error

Tags: excel, error-handling, vlookup, vba

```
If Not IsError(Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SRange(z, lastC), sWks.range("$D:$G"), 3, False)) Then

or

cells(1,1) = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SRange(z, lastC), sWks.range("$D:$G"), 3, False)

or

On Error Resume Next
m1 = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(SRange(z, lastC), sWks.range("$D:$G"), 3, False)
        If m1 > 0 Then
            Cells(e, 3).Value = "Yes"
        Else
            Cells(e, 3).Value = "No"
        End If
```

Alway return `Run-time error ’1004′: Unable to get the VLookup property of the WorksheetFunction class` if do not match the entry

How to catch this error or solve another way this problem?

Comment: Just use `Application.VLookup` rather than `Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use Application.VLookup rather than Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup

The WorksheetFunction.*function_name* versions always return a run-time error if they fail, whereas the Application.*function_name* versions return an error *value* that you can test.